# ParseFacebookUtilsV4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, parsefacebookutils

I cannot compile my Xcode project, it has problems with duplicate ParseFacebookUtilsV4

this is my apple Mach-O Linker Error:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
/directory/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
/directory/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookUtils.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
/directory/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
/directory/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookUtils.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've imported ParseFacebookUtilsV4 with cocoapods, here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ZZZ' do

pod 'Parse'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit',  '4.3.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.3.0'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'


end

target 'ZZZTests' do

end
```

And here is my bridging header:

```
#ifndef FarThings_FarThings_Bridging_Header_h
#define FarThings_FarThings_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtilsV4.h>
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "FBSDKLoginKit.h"
#import <Bolts/BFTask.h>


#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit this before, In my case I upgrade from old version and here's how I fix it. (Main idea is cleanup everything before pod)

1. Remove **all** old **Parse**, **Bolt** and **Facebook** related (all .framework lookup path and embed .framework) until you end up with unknown class.
2. Remove **all** .framework form folder via finder.
3. Clean up your build folder by 'alt+clean' via Xcode.
4. Delete all **Pod** related include all Pod folder via finder.
5. try **pod install** one by one (or all at one if you feeling brave) until it look like this.

> pod 'Parse'
>
> pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
>
> pod 'ParseCrashReporting'

and some other **pod** you need after that.

It work for me, just make sure you remove **all** related.
You can this pod with new project to prove this work before trying with real project.